# How to know whether the object is moving after it is being detected?

Tags: python, object-recognition

If my algorithm detects the type of object, how should I know if that object is moving or not? Suppose a person carrying an umbrella. How to know that the umbrella is moving?

I am working on a project where I want to know whether that particular object belongs to the person entering inside the store.
I was thinking about the bounding boxes(bb) approach where if the person's bb overlaps with the object's bb. But the problem arises when there are multiple objects with a person.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Your title ask for moving object but your post ask about if an object belong to a person. What is your question ?

Comment: sorry for the confusing sentence. If the object moves with a person then it belongs to the person. This is the logic I want to use. I will check the start, middle and final frames to get the results.

Comment: I have tried the overlap between the bounding boxes approach. If the intesection over union between two bounding boxes is large then object belongs to the person . again I will check the frame for that

Answer (score 1):

Either (a) re-recognize it in subsequent frames and then train a network employing a trajectory model to the changing object model parameters or (b) recognize the object and its motion in a single object-trajectory parameterized model from the sequence of sets of detected edges indicating edge movement in the sequence of frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several consecutive frames as an input. If you have dataset of moving/not moving objects, you can use it to train your model. You can use CNNs with additional time dimension in this case, for example.